# I'm getting an error: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression in vb

Tags: vba, ms-access

This is the SQL.

```
dtaadpResult.SelectCommand.CommandText = " SELECT * FROM tblResult WHERE EventID =" & EventID(Counter1) & " AND ORDER BY Time DESCENDING"
```

It happens when I attempt to fill the dataset.

```
dtaadpResult.Fill(dtasetSD, "tblResult")
```

I'm using MS access, do I add paranthesis? How would I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection. Use parameters instead of string concatenation.**

With that obligatory warning out of the way, look at your query text after formatting it:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tblResult
WHERE
    EventID = @eventId
    AND
ORDER BY
    Time DESCENDING
```

The problem is you have an `AND` statement followed by `ORDER BY`, when you should have a predicate clause instead.

Either add another clause, or remove the `AND` operator keyword.

Also, more protips:

1. Avoid hungarian notation and consider using plurals for table names (i.e. use `Results` instead of `tblResult`.
2. Long lines of SQL embedded in code are hard to read, consider formatting your SQL and using multi-line strings instead.
3. **USE PARAMETERISED QUERIES, NOT STRING CONCATENATION** to generate SQL
4. If you're executing a `SELECT` query and passing it to a `DataAdapter` just to fill a `DataTable` or `DataSet` you're wasting memory and CPU cycles, instead use a `DataReader` instead: it's much faster (and with a considerably lower memory overhead).